# Getting likes count by post using sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Can you please help me building the sql query to get all the like for a particular post and i need to do the same for all the posts
and the second option i would required is, if the current logged in user has already liked that particular post, if so i need have a true or false Boolean value.

i want to join both the tables and get total count of likes for a particular post and also if the current user liked the post or not

**Post likes table**

```
    Id                                  PostId                                  LikedBy        LikedOn
9B0B2DEB-47CE-4F6E-B892-35D2F2D3F543    480149F2-BCF4-40F4-3C19-08D7DFC7C616    0F8FAD5B-D9CB-469F-A165-70867728950E    2020-04-15 23:08:26.567
40E7C5F4-AD42-4A22-8BC0-5B0C9F125427    480149F2-BCF4-40F4-3C19-08D7DFC7C616    0F8FAD5B-D9CB-469F-A165-70867728950E    2020-04-15 23:08:10.530
C132E64E-C9A2-471E-9DD9-CB9A342D2DBE    6B989E93-10FE-4131-38B4-08D7DC6856B4    0F8FAD5B-D9CB-469F-A165-70867728950E    2020-04-16 11:43:46.730
32099959-DB24-42F0-A629-F0991163509A    480149F2-BCF4-40F4-3C19-08D7DFC7C616    0F8FAD5B-D9CB-469F-A165-70867728950E    2020-04-15 22:49:44.557
AA606CFF-EAC0-4010-A673-FF682D46AB80    480149F2-BCF4-40F4-3C19-08D7DFC7C616    0F8FAD5B-D9CB-469F-A165-70867728950E    2020-04-16 11:43:54.587
```

**All Posts**

```
Id                                      Title                    UserId                          Post
6B989E93-10FE-4131-38B4-08D7DC6856B4    great                   0F8FAD5B-D9CB-469F-A165-70867728950E    this is great app to build
480149F2-BCF4-40F4-3C19-08D7DFC7C616    What is Lorem Ipsum?    0F8FAD5B-D9CB-469F-A165-70867728950E    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy
```

*here post.userid = postlike.likedby
and post.id = postlike.postid*

i tried this but the query keeps executing with no output

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Tempposts
create table #Tempposts
(
    PostID varchar(50), 
    UserID varchar(50),
    TotalLikes int,
    IsLikedByUser bit
)
Declare @TempPostID varchar(50)
Declare @TempUserID varchar(50)
Declare @TempTotalLikes Int
Declare @TempIsLikedByUser bit
Declare @Id uniqueidentifier
Declare @UserId uniqueidentifier

DECLARE load_cursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT Id, UserId
    FROM tbl_posts

OPEN load_cursor 
FETCH NEXT FROM load_cursor INTO @Id, @UserId
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
    BEGIN 
        SET @TempPostID = @Id
        SET @TempUserID = @UserId
        SET @TempTotalLikes = (select count(*) from tbl_postlikes where PostId = @Id)
        SET @TempIsLikedByUser = (select count(*) from tbl_postlikes where PostId = @Id and LikedBy = @UserId)
        insert into #Tempposts values(@TempPostID, @TempUserID, @TempTotalLikes, @TempIsLikedByUser)
        FETCH NEXT FROM load_cursor INTO @Id, @UserId
    End
Close load_cursor
DeAllocate load_cursor
select * from #Tempposts
Drop table #Tempposts
```

**my table definitions**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_postlikes](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [PostId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [LikedBy] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [LikedOn] [datetime] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_posts](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [Title] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Post] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [UserId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [Created] [datetime] NULL,
    [Updated] [datetime] NULL,
    [IsVisible] [bit] NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [UpdatedBy] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [HasComments] [bit] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: Sure, we can _help_ you. What have you tried and what problems did you encounter?

Comment: i am not sure what is the approach i should follow, this is kind of pretty new to me

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. We don't know the definitions of your tables or how you discern "the current logged in user". You seem to want a `select` statement and mention a `join`. Start there and edit your post to include your attempt and explain what part isn't cooperating. We can answer _specific_ questions, but this isn't a (Home)Work For Free Coding Site.

Comment: There are some great pointers and tools to help you add to your question so we can help you in this post. [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: @HABO i have added table definitions and the sql query, i have used cursor but it keeps running with no output

Comment: Your [`while`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/while-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) loop never advances the cursor since the only statement in the loop is `SET @TempPostID = @Id`. Did you mean to have a `begin`/`end` block in the loop? As the documentation shows `while` can be followed by a single statement or a statement-block, i.e. `begin`/`end`.

Comment: i want the  whole thing to be dynamic, what i am missing here, if while loop do only one statement at a time then how can i do the whole block below inside while loop

`SET @TempPostID = @Id
    SET @TempUserID = @UserId
    SET @TempTotalLikes = (select count(*) from tbl_postlikes where PostId = @Id)
    SET @TempIsLikedByUser = (select count(*) from tbl_postlikes where PostId = @Id and LikedBy = @UserId)
     insert into #Tempposts values(@TempPostID, @TempUserID, @TempTotalLikes, @TempIsLikedByUser)
     FETCH NEXT FROM load_cursor INTO @Id, @UserId`

Comment: @HABO i am getting the below error now
`Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 21
Must declare the scalar variable "@Id".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 24
Must declare the scalar variable "@Id".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 25
Must declare the scalar variable "@UserId".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 26
Must declare the scalar variable "@Id".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 27
Must declare the scalar variable "@Id".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 28
Must declare the scalar variable "@TempPostID".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 29
Must declare the scalar variable "@Id"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query seems to work right, if you have a problem, it is not in this code I hope. But I wonder why you use cursor at all. What you need is something like

```
SELECT 
Id, 
UserId,
(select count(*) from tbl_postlikes where PostId = tbl_posts.Id) as TotalLikes,
(select count(*) from tbl_postlikes where PostId = tbl_posts.Id and LikedBy = @currentUser) as IsLikedByUser
FROM tbl_posts
```

The code you have seem to have a bug in `IsLikedByUser` though. What you test is, that author of the post likes his post, what is probably not what you want. You should send current user as a parameter of the query and test to that user.

And you should definitely add code to fill the tables. I mean this:

```
insert into tbl_posts (id, title, userid, post)
values
('6B989E93-10FE-4131-38B4-08D7DC6856B4', 'great',                '0F8FAD5B-D9CB-469F-A165-70867728950E', 'this is great app to build'),
('480149F2-BCF4-40F4-3C19-08D7DFC7C616', 'What is Lorem Ipsum?', '0F8FAD5B-D9CB-469F-A165-70867728950E', 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy');

insert into tbl_postlikes (Id, PostId, LikedBy, LikedOn)
values
('9B0B2DEB-47CE-4F6E-B892-35D2F2D3F543', '480149F2-BCF4-40F4-3C19-08D7DFC7C616', '0F8FAD5B-D9CB-469F-A165-70867728950E', '2020-04-15 23:08:26.567'),
('40E7C5F4-AD42-4A22-8BC0-5B0C9F125427', '480149F2-BCF4-40F4-3C19-08D7DFC7C616', '0F8FAD5B-D9CB-469F-A165-70867728950E', '2020-04-15 23:08:10.530'),
('C132E64E-C9A2-471E-9DD9-CB9A342D2DBE', '6B989E93-10FE-4131-38B4-08D7DC6856B4', '0F8FAD5B-D9CB-469F-A165-70867728950E', '2020-04-16 11:43:46.730'),
('32099959-DB24-42F0-A629-F0991163509A', '480149F2-BCF4-40F4-3C19-08D7DFC7C616', '0F8FAD5B-D9CB-469F-A165-70867728950E', '2020-04-15 22:49:44.557'),
('AA606CFF-EAC0-4010-A673-FF682D46AB80', '480149F2-BCF4-40F4-3C19-08D7DFC7C616', '0F8FAD5B-D9CB-469F-A165-70867728950E', '2020-04-16 11:43:54.587');
```

Comment: Thank you @antonin Lejsek for providing the query,

Comment: I have made few changes to the query and made it as SP
`CREATE procedure [dbo].[sp_GetAllLikes1](@UserId as varchar(50))
as begin
DECLARE @total int;
SET @total =  (select count(*) from tbl_postlikes where PostId = tbl_posts.Id and LikedBy = @UserId);
SELECT 
*,
(select count(*) from tbl_postlikes where PostId = tbl_posts.Id) as TotalLikes,
(SELECT IIF(@total > 0, 'true', 'false')) as islikedbyuser
FROM tbl_posts
end
Go`